# Configuring NetCDF for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, r, netcdf

I have multidimensional meteodata I want to upload on GeoServer (2.17) using NetCDF format. So far, I don't care about projection other than WGS84. Following a documentation I tried to create in R test file with 1 variable and dimensions in the following order:

3 custom dimensions, lat, long (according to documentation I skip time and z or could I?). However, GeoServer logs showed that all 'custom' axes are non-recognizable

```
Unsupported axis: int here_is_name_of_my_custom_dim(here_is_name_of_my_custom_dim=9)
```

So general question - is it possible to skip time and z dimension and use only customs+2coordinate? If yes, then can anybody point to an example or post/tutorial/whatever to configure such a file (better with R, but Python also works). It's also ok if there is no way around to add 'empty' time and z dimensions (i.e. with 1 value), but it should work in the end.

P.S-  As an addition, I can't even reproduce example with time,z, lat, long dimensions (see R code below).

GeoServer gives error (copied only main part (as I guess, can parse all log))

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

```
library(ncdf4)
d1 = ncdim_def("time", "days since 2020-01-01 0:00:00", 1:5) 
d2 = ncdim_def("z", "meters", 1) 
d3 = ncdim_def("lat", "degrees_north", 1:10) 
d4 = ncdim_def("lon", "degrees_east", 1:5) 

v_def = ncvar_def('myvar', '', list(d1,d2,d3,d4), missval=-9999, prec='float')
nc = nc_create('test.nc', v_def, force_v4=T)
ncvar_put(nc=nc,varid='myvar',vals=1:250, start=c(1,1,1,1), count=c(-1,-1,-1,-1))
```

Comment: It's unclear if your question is how to add a NC file to GeoServer or how to create a valid NC file with R?

Comment: Hi Ian, second part mostly, as here is the problem for now. R is preferred, but not only option (python also ok).